# Custom progressive audio streaming in browser

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, mp3, web-audio-api

Say i like to create my very own progressive streaming mechanicsm in Javascript because i'm finding the browser's built in streaming mechanism not fault-tollerant enough or i like to implement my own custom method over WebSocket. I would like to create a buffer which holds the already downloaded segments of a continous media file (say an arraybuffer or something like that). Is it possible to play this file even if it's not already downloaded from start-to-end?

My only idea was the [Web Audio API which has a noteOn() function](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) for preceisely timing the start of each segment. However i don't know how gapeless this would be. Also it introduces the problem that i have to know exactly where audio files can be cut safely on the server side so the next part can be decoded without any loss and gaps. E.g. mp3's bit reservoir stores audio data in neighbour audio frames even in CBR mode which makes things difficult.

Comment: i have fed middle chunks of mp3 files to an <audio> tag, and it did play them. making it gapless might be harder, but getting it to work with dataURLs should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about creating a [ScriptProcessorNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode-section) that feeds from your incoming buffers? The biggest issue is making sure that the segments are convertible to raw audio samples, but otherwise you could write a simple function in the [onaudioprocess event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioProcessingEvent-section) that pulls in the next available buffer chunk and copies it into the node's output buffers. Since this would be a pull-on-demand mechanism, you wouldn't need to worry about timing segment playback.

Comment: This definitely works. I actually used this exact method in a proof-of -concept a couple months ago. As long as the connection is fast enough, and you take some care to make sure you don't start playback until you've got enough buffers downloaded, it was flawless.

Comment: This seems what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Matt, I'm trying to use this solution but I'm having trouble putting these two parts together.  Could you perhaps post an example?  Thanks!